# How to detect display (video) sources connected using C#/C++?

Tags: video, hdmi

I have a C# application where in i need to detect which all display sources are coonected to the system; for e.g VGA, DVI, HDMI, etc  sources? Is this can be done through any of available classes in .net? .Net would be easier as my application is in WPF. Also I don't know if there is any WMI services are present which i can use to get this information..

Basically i need to search all the video sources connected in the system.

Any ideas/suggestions will be welcomed.

Regards,
Sukhas

Comment: I also was searching for the same thing. And I found this on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link.  `Screen.AllScreens` property will return an array of all displays connected to the system.
[MSDN Link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx)